# DateTime Ticks, check for overlapping dates C#

Tags: c#

Lets say I 2 longs a start and end, which are really two date times converted to ticks. How would I tell if these two values overlap?

Comment: What does it mean for two dates to overlap? Does Monday overlap with Thursday?

Comment: Only two longs? Wouldn't they only overlap if there were equal? It sounds like you're asking when do `3` and `5` overlap, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: *Two pairs* of DateTimes (as ticks or other) can overlap, or two DateTime-TimeSpan sets. Dates don't overlap unless they are the same, but time spans (not TimeSpans), can overlap.

Answer (score 1):

As MPelletier mentioned: you need two pairs of DateTimes:

```
var start1 = new DateTime(2013, 4, 10).Ticks;
var end1 = new DateTime(2013, 4, 20).Ticks;

var start2 = new DateTime(2013, 4, 9).Ticks;
var end2 = new DateTime(2013, 4, 11).Ticks;

if (start2 < end1)
{
    //// Overlapping
}
```